# Is it possible to run asp.net mvc 4 from within a folder of a main website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-6

I have successfully set up an API using ASP.NET MVC 4 on IIS6 (I used [Phil's tutorial](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx)). When testing, we had it as the "Default website" and so there was no conflict with anything else. I am now being asked to set this up within a FOLDER of an existing website (the existing website is in ASP 1.0...and I cannot modify this...so I would some sort of virtual...something?). So basically, if we have https://www.ourcompany.com, they want the API to be available through https://www.ourcompany.com/api/.

Is this even possible? Phil's tutorial talks about setting up a Virtual Application, but I don't have that option in IIS (and if I had, I'm not knowledgeable enough about IIS to know if that would even allow me to access the API that way). I don't want anything that I set up to mess up the current website either, and there are a couple steps in the tutorial that I'll freely admit I don't fully understand.

If your curious as to WHY, the only advantage (besides being "neat") is so that the same SSL Cert can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's definately possible at my work we had a similar setup, IIS6, a .NET 3.5 web, with a .NET 4.0 web nested underneath.

You would just set it up as a virtual directory underneath the parent website, point it to your folder, and ensure the value for the "Execute Permissions" dropdown is "Scripts Only" or above, and the correct .NET framework version selected on the ASP.NET tab.

There may be additional values you may need to over-write in your child web.config file, or, alternatively, wrap the entire parent web config with a "Location" attribute.

*Forgot to mention*, you may need to add manual script mappings for the child web if it doesn't work by default. (This installs the .NET 4.0 script mappings to a specific web) though again not sure if this is required by default. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx

One more thing - If you're using REST (or an extension less URL mapping which I believe an MVC 4 web will use) - You'll need to add a "wild card" script mapping, which basically tells IIS to serve requests with no extension with the .NET 4.0 framework - [See here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/) However where they're referencing .NET 2.0 folders, you'll obviously want to reference the same files but in the .NET 4.0 folders :)

Thanks